# the town where she came from vs. the town which she came from

Tags: usage

I have heard many times ***the town she came from***.  What about ***the town where she came from*** or ***the town which she came from***?

Are both acceptable English?

Answer (score 1):

All three of these are acceptable English, but **"the town she came from"** would be the simplest and most popular choice. (Strictly speaking, you would need to use *that* instead of *which,* but that rule is sometimes ignored in informal speech.)